# Paging toolbar blinks with PDF viwer in sencha touch 2.2

Tags: pdf, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, pdf-viewer

I want to create a view for viewing a pdf from the server.I got this [st2_pdf_panel](https://github.com/SunboX/st2_pdf_panel) after several minutes in google.I followed the demo and copy the pdf.js and PDF.js into my project.

**1** But when the app runs,the paging toolbar will show first before loading the pdf file in the middle of the view and then it will dock to the bottom.

**2** The pdf view does not scroll and the scale looks bad in the iphone screen,i can hardly see the words in the page.

**3** How to zoom in or zoom out ?

**4** Is there any substitue for this solution ?

Below is the code of the view :

```
Ext.define('Myapp.view.PDF',{
    extend : 'Ext.Container',
    requires : ['Ext.ux.panel.PDF'],
    config : {
        items : [
                   {
                            xtype : 'titlebar',
                            docked : 'top',
                            title : 'PDF',
                            items : [
                                {
                                    text : 'back',
                                    ui : 'back',
                                    align : 'left',
                                    listeners : {
                                        tap : function(){
                                            console.log('goback');
                                        }
                                    }
                                }   
                            ]
                },//title bar
                {
                    xtype : 'pdfpanel',
                    height : '100%',
                    src : 'http://cdn.mozilla.net/pdfjs/tracemonkey.pdf',
                    style : {
                        backgroundColor : '#333'
                    },
                    pageScale : 0.5,
                    pageText: 'page {0} of {1}',
                }   
        ]
    }//config
});
```

Comment: There are three demos in the same link you provided. go through them https://github.com/SunboX/st2_pdf_panel/tree/master/demo.  `SimpleViewer` looks good to me.

Comment: I choose another version,then it shows normal.But i got some charset problems when showing pdf with chinese.

Comment: @Mr_Green  I hava got some charset problems with showing pdfs in Chinese，can you help me？

Comment: I don't know about that. If you explain it clearly may be I could help you (or others atleast).